# Manter imagens em linha mesmo em dispositivos moveis

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3, media-queries

Tenho uma `div` que contem alguns ícones, o qual estão alinhados horizontalmente, porem de acordo com o tamanho da tela em que ele é exibido é gerado uma quebra de linha, meu objetivo é prevenir que isso ocorra. mesmo que os ícones sejam redimensionados.

```css
#share-buttons img {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
    display: inline;
    }
```

```html
<!-- I got these buttons from simplesharebuttons.com -->
<div id="share-buttons">
    <!-- Email -->
    <a href="mailto:?Subject=Simple Share Buttons&amp;Body=I%20saw%20this%20and%20thought%20of%20you!%20 https://cncharitas.org.br/">
        <img src="https://i0.wp.com/simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/email.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="Email" width="59" height="59">
    </a>
    
    <!-- Facebook -->
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/clubenavalcharitas/" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://i1.wp.com/simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/facebook.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="Facebook" width="59" height="59">
    </a>
    
    <!-- Google+ -->
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/+ClubeNavalCharitasNiter%C3%B3i" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://i1.wp.com/simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/google.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="Google" width="59" height="59">
    </a>        
    <!-- WhasApp-->
    <a href="http://api.whatsapp.com/send?1=pt_BR&amp;phone=5521971293327&amp;text=entre%20em%20contato%20conosco" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://i0.wp.com/cncharitas.org.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/whasapp.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="WhatsApp" width="59" height="59">
    </a>
<!-- intagram-->
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/cncharitas/" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://i1.wp.com/cncharitas.org.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/intagram.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="instagram" width="59" height="59">
    </a>
</div>
```

Quando a tela é pequena tenho esse resultado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E gostaria de algo parecido com: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os ícones foram reduzidos para se adequar a tela em questão. isso é possível?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remova os valores fixos e atribua relativos.

```css
#share-buttons {
  width: 100%;  
}

#share-buttons a {
  width: 18%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#share-buttons img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 75px;
  max-height: 75px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- I got these buttons from simplesharebuttons.com -->
<div style="width:500px;">
  <div id="share-buttons">
    <!-- Email -->
    <a href="mailto:?Subject=Simple Share Buttons&amp;Body=I%20saw%20this%20and%20thought%20of%20you!%20 https://cncharitas.org.br/">
      <img src="https://i0.wp.com/simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/email.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="Email">
    </a>

    <!-- Facebook -->
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/clubenavalcharitas/" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://i1.wp.com/simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/facebook.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="Facebook">
    </a>

    <!-- Google+ -->
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/+ClubeNavalCharitasNiter%C3%B3i" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://i1.wp.com/simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/google.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="Google">
    </a>
    <!-- WhasApp-->
    <a href="http://api.whatsapp.com/send?1=pt_BR&amp;phone=5521971293327&amp;text=entre%20em%20contato%20conosco" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://i0.wp.com/cncharitas.org.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/whasapp.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="WhatsApp">
    </a>
    <!-- intagram-->
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/cncharitas/" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://i1.wp.com/cncharitas.org.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/intagram.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="instagram">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div style="width:250px;">
  <div id="share-buttons">
    <!-- Email -->
    <a href="mailto:?Subject=Simple Share Buttons&amp;Body=I%20saw%20this%20and%20thought%20of%20you!%20 https://cncharitas.org.br/">
      <img src="https://i0.wp.com/simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/email.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="Email">
    </a>

    <!-- Facebook -->
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/clubenavalcharitas/" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://i1.wp.com/simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/facebook.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="Facebook">
    </a>

    <!-- Google+ -->
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/+ClubeNavalCharitasNiter%C3%B3i" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://i1.wp.com/simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/google.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="Google">
    </a>
    <!-- WhasApp-->
    <a href="http://api.whatsapp.com/send?1=pt_BR&amp;phone=5521971293327&amp;text=entre%20em%20contato%20conosco" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://i0.wp.com/cncharitas.org.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/whasapp.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="WhatsApp">
    </a>
    <!-- intagram-->
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/cncharitas/" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://i1.wp.com/cncharitas.org.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/intagram.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="instagram">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você deve usar algum valor leve em consideração a largura da tela e não um valor fixo, nesse caso usei o `vw` que considera o valor máximo da largura da tela (desconsiderado o tamanho do container), observe que coloquei o mesmo valor tanto pro `width` como pro `height`, também adicione o estilo `display: block; float: left;`

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#share-buttons a {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
#share-buttons img {
    width: 18vw;
    height: 18vw;
    padding: 1vw;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!-- I got these buttons from simplesharebuttons.com -->
<div id="share-buttons">
    <!-- Email -->
    <a href="mailto:?Subject=Simple Share Buttons&amp;Body=I%20saw%20this%20and%20thought%20of%20you!%20 https://cncharitas.org.br/">
        <img src="https://i0.wp.com/simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/email.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="Email" width="59" height="59">
    </a>
    
    <!-- Facebook -->
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/clubenavalcharitas/" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://i1.wp.com/simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/facebook.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="Facebook" width="59" height="59">
    </a>
    
    <!-- Google+ -->
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/+ClubeNavalCharitasNiter%C3%B3i" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://i1.wp.com/simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/google.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="Google" width="59" height="59">
    </a>        
    <!-- WhasApp-->
    <a href="http://api.whatsapp.com/send?1=pt_BR&amp;phone=5521971293327&amp;text=entre%20em%20contato%20conosco" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://i0.wp.com/cncharitas.org.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/whasapp.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="WhatsApp" width="59" height="59">
    </a>
<!-- intagram-->
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/cncharitas/" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://i1.wp.com/cncharitas.org.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/intagram.png?w=840&amp;ssl=1" alt="instagram" width="59" height="59">
    </a>
</div>
```

Você também pode usar o FontAwesome para criar os ícones

```css
html,body, #share-buttons {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100vw;
}
#share-buttons a {
    width: 16vw;
    height: 16vw;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 16vw;
    margin: 2vw;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">

<!-- I got these buttons from simplesharebuttons.com -->
<div id="share-buttons">
    <!-- Email -->
    <a class="fas fa-envelope" href="mailto:?Subject=Simple Share Buttons&amp;Body=I%20saw%20this%20and%20thought%20of%20you!%20 https://cncharitas.org.br/"></a>
    
    <!-- Facebook -->
    <a class="fab fa-facebook-f" href="https://www.facebook.com/clubenavalcharitas/" target="_blank"></a>
    
    <!-- Google+ -->
    <a class="fab fa-google-plus-g" href="https://plus.google.com/+ClubeNavalCharitasNiter%C3%B3i" target="_blank"></a>

    <!-- WhasApp-->
    <a class="fab fa-whatsapp" href="http://api.whatsapp.com/send?1=pt_BR&amp;phone=5521971293327&amp;text=entre%20em%20contato%20conosco" target="_blank"></a>

    <!-- intagram-->
    <a class="fab fa-instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/cncharitas/" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Uma dica.... Cuidado com o vw jovem, vw não é relativo ao pai, é relativo a tela, se o cara tiver um monitor de 42pol isso pode fugir do controle e ficar extremamente desproporcional em relação aos outros elementos...

Comment: Sim @hugocsl, já tinha colocado na resposta que _"o `vw` que considera o valor máximo da largura da tela (desconsiderado o tamanho do container)"_, pode diminuir o tamanho com _media query_

Answer (score -4):

experimente colocar no css:
max-width: 100%;

assim ele irá redimensionar a imagem de acordo com o tamanho do elemento pai dele

Comment: Errata: "*- assim ele irá **limitar** a imagem de acordo com o tamanho do elemento pai dele*"